# How to extract encryption and MAC keys using KDF (X9.63) defined by javacardx.security.derivation

Tags: cryptography, javacard

As per Java Card v3.1 new package is defined javacardx.security.derivation

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javacard/3.1/jc_api_srvc/api_classic/javacardx/security/derivation/package-summary.html

KDF X9.63 works on three inputs: input secret, counter and shared info.
Depends on length of generated key material, multiple rounds on hash is carried out to generated final output.

I am using this KDF via JC API to generated 64 bytes of output (which is carried out by 2 rounds of SHA-256) for a 16 bytes-Encryption Key, a 16 bytes-IV, and a 32 bytes-MAC Key.

Note: This is just pseudo code to put my question with necessary details.

```
DerivationFunction df = DerivationFunction.getInstance(DerivationFunction.ALG_KDF_ANSI_X9_63, false);
df.init(KDFAnsiX963Spec(MessageDigest.ALG_SHA_256, input, sharedInfo, (short) 64);

SecretKey encKey = KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_AES, (short)16, false);
SecretKey macKey = KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_HMAC, (short)32, false);

df.nextBytes(encKey); 
df.nextBytes(IVBuffer, (short)0, (short)16);
df.lastBytes(macKey);
```

I have the following questions:

1. When rounds of KDF are performed? Are these performed during df.init() or during `df.nextBytes()` & `df.lastBytes()`?
2. One KDF round will generate 32 bytes output (considering SHA-256 algorithm) then how API's `df.nextBytes()` & `df.lastBytes()` will work with any output expected length < 32 bytes?
3. In this KDF counter is incremented in every next round then how counter will be managed between `df.nextBytes()` & `df.lastBytes()` API's?

Comment: Hi Maarten Bodewes, I am really inspired from you. Your detailed answers in stack overflow forums are remarkable and those helps others a lot. Please accepts my regards.

Comment: You are welcome :) And I thank Oracle for publishing the API as I've requested back in the day and for publishing a clean class for this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. When rounds of KDF are performed? Are these performed during df.init() or during `df.nextBytes()` & `df.lastBytes()`?

That seems to be implementation specific to me. It will probably be faster to perform all the calculations at one time, but in that case it still makes sense to wait for the first request of the bytes. On the other hand RAM is also often an issue, so on demand generation also makes some sense. That requires a somewhat trickier implementation though.

The fact that the output size is pre-specified probably indicates that the simpler method of generating all the key material at once is at least foreseen by the API designers (they probably created an implementation before subjecting it to peer review in the JCF).

> 2. One KDF round will generate 32 bytes output (considering SHA-256 algorithm) then how API's `df.nextBytes()` & `df.lastBytes()` will work with any output expected length < 32 bytes?

It will commonly return the leftmost bytes (of the hash output) and likely leave the rest of the bytes in a buffer. This buffer will likely be destroyed together with the rest of the state when `lastBytes` is called (so don't forget to do so).

Note that the API clearly states that you have to re-initialize the `DerivationFunction` instance if you want to use it again. So that is a very strong indication that they though of destruction of key material (something that is required by FIPS and Common Criteria certification, not just common sense).

Other KDF's *could* have a different way of returning bytes, but using the leftmost bytes and then add rounds to the right is so common you can call it universal. For the ANSI X9.63 KDF this is certainly the case and it is clearly specified in the standard that way.

> 3. In this KDF counter is incremented in every next round then how counter will be managed between `df.nextBytes()` & `df.lastBytes()` API's?

These are methods of the same class and cannot be viewed separately, so they are not separate API's. Class instances can keep state in anyway they want. It might simply hold the counter as class variable, but if it decided to generate the bytes during `init` or the first `nextBytes` / `lastBytes` call then the counter is not even required anymore.